# Recovering lost tutorial pick, wand etc

Tags: terraria, mods

I'm playing Terraria with the Super Terraria World mod.
I drowned after reaching the boat from the tutorial island. I can't find the items that I lost and I can't return to the beginning to get them except for the sword and the bow.

Comment: You could do a simple reset by redownloading the map and potentially a character is one was provided

Comment: You're using Beta Test software with an active bug report forum, but you come here instead?